# Solving statistics probabilities through Java?

Tags: java, statistics

I'm trying to solve a statistics question by using Java. I ended up using my graphing calculator to solve it after failing to solve it through my terrible programming skills, but it still piqued my interest.

Here is the question prompt:

You have a deck of 52 cards. Aces take the value one, and face cards take the value 10. If we pick 100 cards randomly, with replacement, what is the probability that the sum of the 100 cards is even?

here's what I have so far, but I get NaN when I try to return the result. Sorry if my question is too basic or my programming ability is terrible, but I thought I was on the right track and don't have a clue as to why it doesn't work. Does it have to do with the decimals being very small?

```
    final double EVEN_PROB = 8 / 13;
    final double ODD_PROB = 5 / 13;
    double result = 0;


    for (int count = 0; count <= 100; count++)
    {
        if (count % 2 == 0)
        {
           result += (Math.pow(EVEN_PROB, count)) * (Math.pow(ODD_PROB, (100 - count)));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

EDIT - found a typo in the code, it now returns 0.0 instead of NaN. I had the for loop going up to 200 instead of 100

Comment: that is because `Math.pow(ODD_PROB, (100 - count))` will start returning `Infinity` as soon as count goes beyond `100`.

Comment: Changed it, was a typo. I meant to type 100

Any ideas on why it returns 0.0 instead of the actual probability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem, which Rahul pointed out, is that 8/13 is integer division, because both operands are integers, even though you declare the resulting variable as a `double`.  So it returns 0.  You need to use `8.0/13.0` and `5.0/13.0`, as you did.

The bigger problem is that your formula is wrong.  Say `count = 50`; at this point, you're attempting to compute the probability that you draw 50 even cards and 50 odd cards.  Your formula computes (8/13)<sup>50</sup>(5/13)<sup>50</sup>.  What this does is compute the probability that the first card is even, the second card is even, ... the 50th card is even, the 51st card is odd, the 52nd card is odd ... and the 100th card is odd.  But that's only one of many, many possible orders of cards you can draw.  You won't be counting any of the other possible sequences that add up to 50 even cards and 50 odd cards.

To fix this, you need to multiply

```
Math.pow(EVEN_PROB, count) * Math.pow(ODD_PROB, (100 - count))
```

by a *combination* function.  If `count` is 50, this will be the number of combinations of 100 things, taken 50 at a time, often written C(100,50).  For nonnegative integers *m* and *n* where *m* >= *n*, C(*m*,*n*) equals

```
      m!
-------------
 n! (m - n)!
```

But you shouldn't use factorials when computing it.  If you expand this and cancel out some identical factors, you'll get

```
m * (m-1) * (m-2) * ... * (m-n+1)
---------------------------------
        1 * 2 * ... * n
```

Note that there are the same number of factors in the numerator as the denominator.  The best way to compute this and avoid overflow is to start with 1, then multiply by *m*/1, then (*m*-1)/2, then (*m*-2)/3, etc., something you can do easily with a loop.

Then, if you write a method `comb` to compute the combination function, you would add this to `result`:

```
Math.pow(EVEN_PROB, count) * Math.pow(ODD_PROB, (100 - count)) * comb(100,count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basics of division says that int/int = int.
Therefore your variable EVEN_PROB, ODD_PROB are equal to zero.
You might want to try this :

```
final double EVEN_PROB = 8.0 / 13.0;
final double ODD_PROB = 5.0 / 13.0;
```

Comment: Ok, just changed my code and now my result is equal to 1.3482760979229682E-21 when the program ends. Surely this isn't correct?

Comment: Result is wrong because the equation for result is not correct.                For count =1 sum will not be even(1 even + 99 odds is odd). Similarly, you have to eliminate other cases.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal he's already eliminating those cases, did you see his `if` statement?  Besides, if he's adding things he shouldn't be adding, the end result wouldn't be way too small.

Comment: That's why I have the if statement, though. The result is only changed when count%2 == 0, or when count is an even number. When count is an odd number the equation for result isn't called

Comment: Result is wrong because the equation for result is not correct.                For count =1 sum will not be even(1 even + 99 odds is odd). Similarly, you have to eliminate other cases. Also you have to arrange those possible combinations